# Webhook security in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

We are developing a google action with a fullfilment in a cloud function in
GCP. 
We want to know how is the best way to securize this cloud function:

1. It is possible use a private cloud function as fullfilment and avoid
   requests from others origins to dialogflow?
2. It is possible include a rate limit and quota in our cloud function?
3. It is possible to limit the number of concurrent request?
4. Are there some recomendation about certificates or similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Noelia, thank you for joining Stackoverflow and asking your question. It would help people that answer questions if you narrow down your question to one single problem. The way your question is structured at the moment, it is 4 questions in one, this makes it difficult to give you a single answer that covers all your questions. If you need help with asking questions, have a look at the Stackoverflow help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is possible use a private cloud function as fullfilment and avoid requests from others origins to dialogflow?

The short answer is that your fulfillment must be publicly accessible. Your cloud function cannot be private.

If you want, Dialogflow's Fulfillment section lets you add custom auth or headers. You may be able to use this to only enable requests with this header go through.

[image]

> It is possible include a rate limit and quota in our cloud function?
>   It is possible to limit the number of concurrent request?

I'm going to suggest not to have any sort of rate limiting. If each request is authentic, you'd end up creating a bad user experience if your fulfillment keeps going down.

> Are there some recomendation about certificates or similar?

Cloud Functions are all HTTPS by default, so I'm not sure what certificates you'd need or want in this case.

Comment: As an adittion to the answer. Actions on google can do authorization from the sdk, this way the webhook will only accept calls from your agent. Any other request will receive a 403. https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhook/reference/verify-requests

Comment: Thanks to both, I think the jordi solution it's the better options. But in our case we are using dialogflow not actionssdk.

Is it possible use dialogflow to verify the request? How can manage both library in this case?